# Create an Expanding Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

OS: Linux Centos 6.5 / Centos 7
Machine: "Special" **2.5 Terabytes of Physical Memory** (Yes, really)
Programming Language: R

**Problem**:
In R, the practice (appears to be) to allocate before the loop a matrix as big as the final result. In this case, the ***final*** matrix size is undetermined at initiation.

Thus, what is the cleanest way of creating an expanding matrix in R?

A key point is that I wanted to avoid the overhead of a memory copy at the point of expansion. **If that is the only way, that would be OK but not preferred**

**Important:** I am very familiar with kernel level programming, kernel level memory management, page handling systems, etc. **I am new to R, and learning R. (It is very interesting, and useful)** In this instance, I am specifically trying to create a scenario to demonstrate memory expansion of a matrix without pre-allocation of memory, that or a fall back to allocation of size N matrix extensions (incremental expansion using memory chunks).

**Problem Example**

Ok, in the described scenario we might Create matrix A, create expanded matrix B, copy A to B then perform operation on larger matrix.

An alternate approach would be to expand A, populate result and iterate...

For example, we might start by using outer(), however **"outer()"** creates a *new* matrix at each invocation. I was looking to expand the existing matrix...

```
x<- outer(1:2,1:2,"*")
x

    [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2  
[2,]    2    4
```

...

```
x<-outer(1:3,1:3,"*")
x

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    3    6    9
```

...

```
x<-outer(1:3,1:3,"*")
x

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    2    4    6    8
[3,]    3    6    9   12
[4,]    4    8   12   16
```

Hence, my question:

"What is the preferred way to create a dynamically allocated matrix in R, without pre-allocation of a large matrix?"

Thanks in advance to everyone for the pointers and reading recommendations. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You will find a lot of information about optimization of the code in the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should allocate before the loop a matrix as big as the final result and then, in each iteration, you fill the values. In your example (if I understood correctly how the values are filled), you can try:

```
 #set the dimension of the final matrix
 n<-10
 #create the matrix
 res<-matrix(ncol=n,nrow=n)
 #fill the values
 res[1,1]<-1
 for (i in 2:n) {
   tmp<-c(i,(i+2):(2*i))
   res[i,1:i]<-tmp
   res[1:i,i]<-tmp
   print(res)
 }
```

Comment: Nicola,

Thanks for the example - much appreciated. 

The issue is that I do not want to allocate a matrix prior to running the algorithm as the size of the result is unknown. The result is bounded but can be very large.